# How to get the user.email config using gitpython ?

Tags: gitpython

I have a repo initialized as

```
r = git.Repo.init(dirPath)
```

How can I get the user.email field for the git config for that repo using gitpython?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After looking into the [source](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/7a6ca8c40433400f6bb3ece2ed30808316de5be3/git/config.py#L510)  of gitpython this is one way I managed to do it.

```
r = git.Repo.init(dirPath)
reader = r.config_reader()
field = reader.get_value("user","email")
```

Comment: In case the user.email config does not exist, the get_value function may throw and exception or return a default value. The user can affect that behavior by passing a default parameter named "default" to the get_value function.

Comment: How to do this without `Repo` object? Like getting global settings.

Comment: That's not yet possible, see https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/775

Comment: Quick update: To access global settings directly, you can now use `git.config.GitConfigParser().get_value(...)` (see https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/pull/950)